# Django, CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request, cors

Can't figure out what's wrong with my Django DRF api endpoint. I'm getting a CORS error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/. (Reason: CORS
> header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Problem is, I followed every step online to fix this.

- I've installed 'django-cors-headers'
- Added *corsheaders* app to    INSTALLED_APPS above *rest_framework*
  and the app that includes api    endpoint.
- Added cors middleware to the top of the middleware list    in
  settings.py
- Added 'CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS =    ('http://localhost:3000' # React
  app) (Also tried with CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW = True)
- Quadruple-checked that API POST request includes a trailing slash.

Nothing seems to fix it. Am I forgetting something? Thanks for any help.

This is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',

]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
    'http://localhost:3000',  # for localhost (REACT Default)
)


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

Not sure how revelant it is, but If I send POST request from insomnia, it works fine, but from React, it doesn't, this is my react request just in case:

```
const postSomeData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.post(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
      { promptQuery: "pls just work already" },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The code looks fine ,it seems middleware order issue. Would you try putting corsheader middle between sessionmiddleware and commonmiddleware ..
something like this :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', #here
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

since the order of middleware matters.

Comment: Did this. Doesn't seem to change anything tho. Still facing the same issue.